# Reading a value and use it without declaring an extra variable just as in Java's sc.next()

Tags: c++, c, scanf

In java you can do something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<something;i++){
    total+=sc.nextInt(); // <<< Doesn't require an extra variable
}
```

And my question is: can you do something similar in C or C++ ? and if there is, is it better?

This is what I currently do:

```
int total;
int aux; // <<< Need an extra variable to read input
for(int i = 0; i<something;i++){
    scanf("%d",&aux);
    total+=aux; // <<< and add the read value here
}
```

Comment: In c++ we usually use `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& val)` not `scanf()`. The latter is [tag:c]-style, and if you really want to have it, tag your question appropriately please!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am not particularly looking for a solution in C or C++ just one that works the best, I already edited the question.

Comment: In one line: `total+=atoi(fgets(aux, 256, stdin));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way to do it in C++ would be something like this:

```
int total = std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                            std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
                            0);
```

As it stands, this reads all the `int`s it can from the input file rather than requiring a separate specification of the number of input values. You could specify an `N` if you wanted to badly enough, but at least in my experience, you're not very likely to want that.

If you really want to specify N directly, the cleanest way to handle the situation would probably be to define an `accumulate_n` that works about like `std::accumulate`:

```
template <class InIt, class T>
T accumulate_n(InIt in, size_t n, T init) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
       init += *in++;
    return init;
}
```

You'd use this about like the previous version, but (obviously enough) specifying the number of values to read:

```
int total = accumulate_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
                         something,
                         0);
```

I suppose I should add that (especially for production code) you'd probably want to add some constraints on the template parameters in the `accumulate_n` definition above. I also haven't tried to do anything about the possibility of bad input, such as containing something other than a number, or simply containing fewer items than specified. These can be dealt with, but offhand I don't remember how Java deals with them; I'd probably have to do some thinking/research to find/figure out exactly what reaction to such problems would be most appropriate.

Comment: _"The obvious way ..."_ Well, if this is really _obvious_ is arguable, but you're absolutely right with this solution without needing an auxiliary variable of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It seems obvious to *me*... :-)

Comment: _"It seems obvious to me."_ Matter of experience it seems ;-) ... Could you improve your answer, on pointing out what actually could make up the `// break on 'something'` condition?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I've added code to show reading a fixed number of items like the original does.

Comment: I've also been editing my answer a bit. Let's see how all of this flies off ;-) ...

Answer (score 0):

Reading a number of variables from an input stream in c++ usually looks like follows (regarding your sample):

```
int total = 0;
int aux;
while(std::cin >> aux) {
     // break on 'something' condition
     total += aux;
}
```

So, I don't see a way how to do it *without an auxiliary variable*, that actually receives the value read from the `std::istream`, unless you provide a wrapper class yourself, that just provides that *java like* behavior.

> *"can you do something similar in C or C++ ? and if there is, is it better?"*

I doubt it's worth to write such wrapper class for `std::istream` in c++ (You can just consider to use the [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) algorithm as mentioned in [@JerryCoffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640070/1413395)).

For [c](/questions/tagged/c) language, there's no alternate choice, I actually can see/know about.